# find the area under the curve from these 2 functions

Tags: calculus

Find the area under the curves $y=x+1$; $y=\cos{x}$ and the $x$-axis.

---

I'm not sure about this exercise, how to do it?

I have sketched their graphs, but I do not know how to find the area.
[The graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o8tZ.jpg)

Comment: Would you please attach your sketch? I am asking because based on your data, I could not identify the region whose area is to be computed. Or do we have two assignments here?

Comment: Ok I uploaded but  please say if i did it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Integrating it with definite integrals. Take limit as the two points of axis  , under which u want to find the area.